# Right-aligned pyramid

Tags: c

I just started CS 50 and there's a challenge to make a right-aligned pyramid. In the code below it it works well for the first time round but it prints this:

```
  #
  #  #
  #  # #
```

I don't understand why.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void row(int i) {
    for (int y = 0; y < i ; y++) {
        int k = 3 - i;

        if (k > 0 ) {
            for (int x = 0 ; x < k ; x++) {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        printf("#");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int len = 3;

    for (int ye = 0; ye < len ; ye++) {
        row(ye+1);
    }
}
```

I also replaced the k = 3 -y with
-i but that prints

```
  #
 # #
###
```

I ended up solving the challenge in the bed but I'm still not getting what's wrong here if anyone can explain that would awesome and greatly appreciated

For context I was expecting this

```
  #
 ##
###
```

Comment: You are doing the padding inside the loop that draws individual `#` characters. Move that to happen before this loop.

Comment: Essentially each row needs two *consecutive* loops (not nested like you have): One for the spaces, and one for the hashes. For a length of `3`, the first row the space-loop should iterate 2 times and the hash-loop 1 time. The second row should loop the space-loop 1 time, and the hash-loop 2 times. The last row the space-loop should iterate 0 times, and the hash loop 3 times. I hope you start to see the pattern. Now use pen and paper to try and figure out the rows for other values of `len`, then try to generalize it (and don't hard-code *magic numbers* like `3` in your code).

Comment: A nice shortcut to adding some number of spaces is to use the arbitrary string padding field with `printf` -- _e.g._ `printf("%*s", 3-i, "");` -- that prints an empty string padded to a width of `3-i`.

Comment: Have you tried to ```debug``` your code, step through every loop iteration's operation and see for yourself how it works?

Answer (score 2):

Your `row` function needs two *separate* loops.

- One loop to print spaces
- One loop to print hashes, `#`

These loops should then result in that `len` characers are printed. It would also be simpler if you extracted the loop-printing part into a separate function that could print as many of a specific character as you want.

It could look like this:

```c
void print(char ch, int len) {
    while (len-- > 0) {
        putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

Now, in `row` you only need to call this looping and printing function twice. Once for spaces and once for `#`. The function also needs to know how many characters to print in total, so add a parameter, `len`, for that.

```c
void row(int hashes, int len) {
    // the two calls below will result in a total of `len` characters
    // to be printed:
    print(' ', len - hashes);  // spaces
    print('#', hashes);        // hashes
    putchar('\n');
}
```

And in `main` you then need to send in how wide each row should be too:

```c
int main(void) {
    int len = 3;

    for (int ye = 0; ye < len; ye++) {
        row(ye + 1, len);
        //          ^^^
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Ted Lyngmo's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78023623/15261315), we can build a null-terminated string for each line, then use the built-in features of `printf` to pad each line.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 3

char *repeat_char(char *dest, const char ch, size_t n);

int main(void) {
    char str[LEN + 1];

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= LEN; i++) 
        printf("%*s\n", LEN, repeat_char(str, '#', i));
}

char *repeat_char(char *dest, const char ch, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        dest[i] = ch;

    dest[n] = '\0';

    return dest;
}
```

Output:

```
  #
 ##
###
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more generic approach:

```
typedef enum
{
    LEFT,RIGHT
}PYR_ALIGNN_t;

void print(unsigned n, PYR_ALIGNN_t align)
{
    char chars[] = {'#', ' '};
    unsigned counter = 0;
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for(unsigned ch = 0; ch < n; ch++)
            printf("%c", ((align == RIGHT) ? (n - ch - 1) > row : ch <= row ) ? chars[!(align == LEFT)] : chars[align == LEFT]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    print(6,LEFT);
    printf("\n");
    print(6,RIGHT);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qE4z89bGs

```
#     
##    
###   
####  
##### 
######

     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```